# Corporate tax & GST/HST tax - Canada

Tags: taxes, canada, small-business, ontario, gst

I've started self incorporated small business in Canada, registered with Ontario province in 2017.

As per [corporate tax structure](https://www.canada.ca/en/revenue-agency/services/tax/businesses/topics/corporations/corporation-tax-rates.html), both corporate tax return and GST/HST return is filed by end of fiscal year, for 
 my business.

---

What is the formula for calculating *corporate tax* & *GST/HST tax* for the business income per fiscal year? Ontario province..